# Is there any reason to choose P4/P6 SSD disks over S4/S6 HDD in Azure

Tags: azure

I'm looking at the table that lists the IOPS/Capacity/Throughput of Azure Managed Virtual disks and something did not make sense to me:

[image]

As you can see above, S4/S6 type HDD disks have both higher IOPS & Throughput and is also cheaper. Why on earth should anyone choose those over the cheaper disks? That doesn't make sense and I'm sure I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: i guess latency should be completely different

Comment: that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

There are different use cases for "as many IOPS as possible", "moderate IOPS, but tens of ms latency is not good", and "big, slow, and cheap".

The solid state disk are expected to have more consistent latency.

> Standard HDD Managed Disks use Hard Disk Drive (HDD) based Storage media. They are best suited for dev/test and other infrequent access workloads that are less sensitive to performance variability.

Also look at the Standard SSD tier, currently in preview. Similar IOPS and throughput to HDD, that is to say, not increasing with size.

Only Azure knows exactly why they priced and set quotas that way.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing that has not been mentioned is SLA. If you want the Single Instance SLA on your VM then they must be running Premium storage, not standard.